# How do I save data in R to an existing dataset in an existing Excel file?

Tags: r, forms, shiny, xlsx

I am creating a form in Shiny R and when the user inputs some information, I want that information to then be appended to the bottom of an existing dataset in an existing xlsx file.

So far I've tried using `write.xlsx()` with `append = TRUE` to add to an existing file, but this just creates a new sheet in the file. From there I tried specifying the sheet I want the data to be written to (`sheet = 'Data'`), but it tries to make a new sheet with that name instead and gets mad that it already exists.

Is this something that's even possible with `write.xlsx()` or will I have to find a different method to do this?

**Edit**

I think it would actually be helpful if I give a little more info about the app I'm making. The app is also being used to analyze the data in the existing file. This is why I just want to add to it, rather than create a new file.

**Edit 2**

For the most part, I seem to have things working correctly thanks to the suggestions below in the comments. With the exception of one issue I can't seem to fix. In the form, every time you submit new data it adds an additional column of numbers to the dataset, which I definitely don't want! Is there a way to prevent this from happening? As of now I am using `bind_rows()` to merge the data and I've also tried `rbind()`, `rbind_all()`, `smartbind()`, and I'm sure maybe one or two more I'm forgetting at the moment, with no luck.

Comment: Read in the existing excel file to a data.frame, append to that and then use write.xlsx() to write out to file. I suggest naming it with shiny or something unique in the name, so that you don't lose your original excel file having the data

Comment: Is there a way to do this without creating a new file? I want to just add to the original so it can be used in the app after new data has been added.

Comment: Ya write out to same file that your read in. As good practice, after you read it in, create a backup file

Comment: Wouldn't I just run into the same issue though? Or is the idea to write over the data in the file with the data+new data? If it's the second I'm not exactly sure how to do that with xlsx and keep running into the issue of a new sheet getting created or R getting mad that the sheet name already exists. Maybe I'm just really misunderstanding.

Comment: It's the second. Append to the data.frame like so `data_frm_file <-read_xlsx(...), data_to_file <-append(data_frm_file, new_data), write_xlsx(data_to_file).

Comment: This might be a much deeper problem that I'll have to spend time with. This solution does work, but only once, so it seems like this will be a bigger thing with shiny I'll have to figure out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197897/discussion-between-infominer-and-alex-morrison).

Comment: I can't at the moment

Comment: No worries! you need to read the data file in again as shiny only reads it once unless you reload the whole app. 
Interesting that it worked only once. I suspect as you only read in the file once and after writing it out haven't read it back in. So you need to have a routine to execute the data loading function again if file on disk has changed. and there are better ways to append to file. here's a hint https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactiveFileReader.html for reading in file again.

Comment: **Don't use an excel file**, use a database instead! (Even SQLite is a much better option, although it is file based as well). The problem is that with constant reading and writing in multiple sessions an excel file is gonna be locked all the time.

Comment: I think for the most part I got things working except I'm having issues with merging the two in R. Is there a way to do it without an extra column of numbers being added?